# How can I repair a sticking temperature gauge on heating valve?

Tags: plumbing

The plumbing for my building heating system has temperature gauges on the outlet and inlet pipes. One of these gauges sticks - I can make it show the correct temperature by tapping the gauge quite hard or by flexing the dial.

[image: Temparature Gauge]

[image: Grub screw]

It looks like it is held in place by a grub-screw. Is it possible to replace these gauges and are there suppliers in the UK?

Comment: Can't see from the picture...I'd suspect the gauge simply is screwed into the valve body and that screw is for pressure relief, not a set screw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to replace those gages... The most important step will be to make sure the system is off and full dis-pressurized before you try to remove the old gage.  @PeterLoron is correct that the brass screw in thingy on the top (technical term) is for releasing pressure. You can find replacement valves in a variety of on-line stores such as: [here](http://www.houseneeds.com/shop/heatingproducts/hydronicheating/gauges/temperaturegaugeindexpage.asp), [here](http://www.pexsupply.com/Boshart-TW25-CB2-250-25-1-2-NPT-25-Face-Snap-Well-Thermometer-7228000-p), or [here](http://www.pexsupply.com/pex/control/category/~category_id=864/~refine=200864+4294959988).  When you remove your thermometer from the line, the back should look like below: 
[image: Back of temperature gage.]
<sub>(source: [pexsupply.com](http://s3.pexsupply.com/images/products/zoom/tw25-cb2-250-25-2.jpg))</sub>  .

These valves come in a variety of sizes and different thread patterns and in a few cases, if when you look in the back you cannot see the hex shape to get a wrench on in the back, a few are even soldered in (you may need some help to replace this type if you're not familiar with soldering, they can be touchy).  You may decide to replace it with a temp/pressure gage as well.